# SSIS Package stopped working with Error code: 0x80004005

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I got this SSIS package working this past December. It only runs on Friday mornings. Last Friday it failed with this error message:

> Package:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\\ServerShare\IT\Reports\Export Templates\YoderReport.xlsx'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.".

I've checked out a couple of other questions that were similar, but they did not answer my question. I have checked to make sure that no one has that file open.

The file in question is a template that is copied over then populated, so no one should have it open, to begin with.

I've tried changing the `RetainSameConnection` to `True`, but no difference. I have run it in debug mode, and it works fine.

Anyone got any ideas how to clear this up so it runs automatically again?

**UPDATE**

After some more testing, it appears that the file is getting the data, but isn't being copied. Here is what I have setup:

- I have a `File System Task` that copies a template from my template
  folder to my Export folder.
- Then I have a `Data Flow Task`
- - Begins with a OLE DB Source that runs a SQL script to pull data
- - Runs a `Data Conversion` to update a couple of fields to the correct format
- - `Excel Destination` is used for the output. (This is the template that was copied to the Export folder
- - There is also a `Flat File Destination` just in case there are any errors
- Then back to the Control Flow with another `File System Task`, this one moves the file from the Export folder to its final destination on a shared drive

When I run this from VS 2015 it works fine and creates the file. When I run this from the SQL Agent job it fails with the above error message. The only thing that I can think of is that in the `Data Flow Task` the `Excel Destination` isn't releasing the file before the final `File System Task` tries to copy it? But if that is the case, why did that just start happening now?

Comment: Are you using any script component to write data into Xlsx? if yes, then ensure to close the file.

Comment: @Kalyan I am not using a script. This is built in Visual Studio 2015 then saved as a .dtsx package.

Comment: Maybe someone changed the permissions without you noticing. It's easy to check. Login or RunAs that user and see if you can open the file. Another thing to try is just make a copy of the file and try and open the copy. Lastly, use windows tool to confirm that no one has it open

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid no one else can change the permissions, I'm the admin and no one else has the permissions to do that. I'm going to try the other suggestion of copying the file and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem in the filepath, as you can see the file path start with one single backslash:

```
\ServerShare\IT\Reports\Export Templates\YoderReport.xlsx
```

Maybe it should start with double back slash `\\` if it is on the network

```
\\ServerShare\IT\Reports\Export Templates\YoderReport.xlsx
```

Or the Partition is missed --> Incomplete path

**Check the way that the file path is provided to the connection manager *(if you are using expressions)***

---

Also based on this [microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/the-microsoft-access-database-engine-cannot-open-the-file-nameit-is-already-open), there is two possible causes:

1. You must have permission to read data in the specified file in order to view its data. To change your permission assignments, see your system administrator or the table or query's creator.
2. You tried to open the indicated file exclusively, but another user already has the file open.

Comment: It does have the "\\" at the beginning of the file path, I just didn't escape it in the quoted text. I do have the permissions set correctly as this ran fine for almost a month. I'm not able to find any other copies of the file open anywhere else that would prevent me from opening it again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an access issue. Ensure that the Agent Service Account is running with full rights to the network share path. Maybe you can try with your credentials on the Agent Server.

Also, Ensure that your Excel destination connection string supports .xlsx.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\path\xxx.xlsb;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES";
```

Changing “`Excel 12.0`” to “`Excel 12.0 Xml`” will tell the provider to output in .xslx format instead.